Why does the app work for a certain period of time upon launching and then gets frozen?
I'm creating a simple windows app using golang's win library github.com/lxn/win but running into a problem (as mentioned in the title) after couple of seconds of using the app.
Here is my main.go code:
package main

import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    w32 "github.com/lxn/win"
)

// Edit ID
const IDC_MAIN_EDIT = 101

func MakeIntResource(id uint16) *uint16 {
    return (*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(id)))
}

func WndProc(hWnd w32.HWND, msg uint32, wParam, lParam uintptr) uintptr {
    switch msg {
    case w32.WM_CREATE:
        var hfDefault w32.HFONT
        var hEdit w32.HWND

        hEdit = w32.CreateWindowEx(w32.WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("EDIT"), syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(""), w32.WS_CHILD|w32.WS_VISIBLE|w32.WS_VSCROLL|w32.WS_HSCROLL|w32.ES_MULTILINE|w32.ES_AUTOVSCROLL|w32.ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 0, 0, 100, 100, hWnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, w32.GetModuleHandle(nil), nil)
        if hEdit == 0 {
            w32.MessageBox(hWnd, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Could not create edit box."), syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Error"), w32.MB_OK|w32.MB_ICONERROR)
        }

        hfDefault = (w32.HFONT)(w32.GetStockObject(w32.DEFAULT_GUI_FONT))
        w32.SendMessage(hEdit, w32.WM_SETFONT, uintptr(hfDefault), lParam)
    case w32.WM_SIZE:
        var hEdit w32.HWND
        var rcClient w32.RECT

        w32.GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient)

        hEdit = w32.GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT)
        w32.SetWindowPos(hEdit, 0, 0, 0, rcClient.Right, rcClient.Bottom, w32.SWP_NOZORDER)

    case w32.WM_CLOSE:
        w32.DestroyWindow(hWnd)
    case w32.WM_DESTROY:
        w32.PostQuitMessage(0)
    default:
        return w32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)
    }
    return 0
}

func WinMain() int {
    hIcon := w32.LoadImage(0, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("lithium.ico"), w32.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, w32.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
    if hIcon == 0 {
        panic("LoadImage failed")
    }

    hInstance := w32.GetModuleHandle(nil)
    lpszClassName := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("WNDclass")
    var wcex w32.WNDCLASSEX

    wcex.CbSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(wcex))
    wcex.Style = w32.CS_HREDRAW | w32.CS_VREDRAW
    wcex.LpfnWndProc = syscall.NewCallback(WndProc)
    wcex.CbClsExtra = 0
    wcex.CbWndExtra = 0
    wcex.HInstance = hInstance
    wcex.HIcon = w32.HICON(hIcon)
    wcex.HCursor = w32.LoadCursor(0, MakeIntResource(w32.IDC_ARROW))
    wcex.HbrBackground = w32.COLOR_WINDOW + 11

    wcex.LpszMenuName = nil

    wcex.LpszClassName = lpszClassName
    wcex.HIconSm = w32.LoadIcon(hInstance, MakeIntResource(w32.IDI_APPLICATION))
    w32.RegisterClassEx(&wcex)
    hWnd := w32.CreateWindowEx(
        w32.WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, lpszClassName, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Lithium"),
        w32.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|w32.WS_VISIBLE,
        w32.CW_USEDEFAULT, w32.CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, nil)

    w32.ShowWindow(hWnd, w32.SW_SHOWDEFAULT)
    w32.UpdateWindow(hWnd)

    var msg *w32.MSG = (*w32.MSG)(unsafe.Pointer(w32.GlobalAlloc(0, (unsafe.Sizeof(w32.MSG{})))))
    defer w32.GlobalFree(w32.HGLOBAL(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))

    for w32.GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) != 0 {
        w32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        w32.DispatchMessage(msg)
    }

    w32.GdiplusShutdown()

    return int(msg.WParam)
}

func main() {
    WinMain()
}

Would like to know what am I doing wrong and hopefully find a solution.

I don't know about this API, but UI code often needs to call runtime.LockOSThread to make sure the calling goroutine isn't moved to a different OS thread.
